# Finding center of circle from 3 coordinates

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

How would I solve this question (from the SAT):

> In the coordinate plane,the points $F (-2,1)$, $G (1,4)$, and $H (4,1)$ lie on a circle with center P. What are the coordinates of point P ?
>
> $a)   (0,0)$
>
> $b)   (1,1)$
>
> $c)   (1,2)$
>
> $d)   (1,-2)$
>
> $e)   (2.5,2.5)$

I don't know how to find it quickly.

I can only find it through making $3$ equations in the form $(x-b)^2 + (y-h)^2 = r^2$.

Is there a fast way to find this? The question is only level. I am guessing they are assuming that point $F$ and $H$ are directly opposite in the circle but this is not stated explicitly.

Comment: First, I would shift the coordinate plane by (2, -1) such that your points are now (0, 0), (6, 0), (3, 3). Then it is easy to see the relationship between the points. The second is 6 over from the first and the third is half the distance of these two points to the right and half up. It makes a right triangle! So the center is halfway between the first and second points. The radius is clearly 3. So it is at (3, 0). now subtract the (2, -1) and you get (1, 1). The answer is B.

Comment: Since F and H are hroizontally aligned, then P is restricted to being on the vertical line halfway between them

Comment: I assume there is a formula or some other (easier) way to figure that out. That was just looking at it and figuring it out intuitively. I haven't really studied geometry.

Comment: Could you not simply check the distance from the center $P$ to each of the points? If all three distances are equal, it must be a circle.

Comment: Adding to some other answers, if a circle goes through two points, its center must be somewhere on the perpendicular bisector of the segment between those points. (In this case, there are three segments, and three perpendicular bisectors, and those three bisectors must intersect at a single point.) You could sketch the three points and also sketch any two of the perpendicular bisectors, whichever you find easiest to sketch. Where they cross is the center of the circle.

Comment: @SteveKass That's what my answer relies on. It's of course faster (in this case at least) than the accepted answer... though the OP was asking for a _fast way_ to solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a somewhat more "brute-force" (and arguably faster) method to this. Recall a set a points all share the same distance to a common point if and only if they all lay on a circle around that point. With that logic, it's simply a matter of checking distances.

(a)

$d((0,0), (-2,1))=\sqrt{(-2)^2+1^2}=\sqrt{5}$

$d((0,0), (1,4))=\sqrt{1^2+4^2}=\sqrt{17}\neq\sqrt{5}$

Not that one...

(b)

$d((1,1), (-2,1))=\sqrt{(1+2)^2+(1-1)^2}=\sqrt{9}=3$

$d((1,1), (1,4))=\sqrt{(1-1)^2+(1-4)^2}=\sqrt{9}=3$

$d((1,1), (4,1))=\sqrt{(1-4)^2+(1-1)^2}=\sqrt{9}=3$

Found it. The answer is (b). You can verify the rest of the answers don't work, if you have time.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a Multiple Choice question and since all the coordinates are nice whole numbers, then I would say just plot all the answers and see which one works.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen Douglas Allen commented, $F$ and $H$ are horizontally aligned and the center should be on the perpendicular bissector; hence, its abscissa is $(-2+4)/2=1$ (that's probably why most suggested answers have 1 as first coordinates...).

And $H$ and $G$ are symmetric with respect to $y=x$, so the center should be on the first bisector. In other words, both coordinates should be equal. Note that this observation simply stems from the fact that $(1,4)$ is the reverse of $(4,1)$; no need for a drawing.

In the end, the center is at the intersection of both: $(1,1)$.